# Adding Auto-Play to an image slider without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add auto-play to my existing image slider which has navigation buttons. I haven't found a suitable way to make both auto-play and nav buttons to work.

Can anyone help me add the auto-play functionality to the below code.

I need a solution that doesn't depend on javascript or jquery.

CSS file:

```css
.carousel-wrapper{
height:400px;
position:relative;
width:600px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.carousel-item{
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
padding:25px 50px;
opacity:0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
.arrow{
border: solid black;
border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 12px;
}

.arrow-prev{
left:-30px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.arrow-next{
right:-30px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}


/*Select every element*/
[id^="item"] {
    display: none;
}

.item-1 {
z-index: 2;
opacity: 1;
background-image: url("images/1.jpg");
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.item-2{
background-image: url("images/2.jpg");
background-size:cover;
}
.item-3{
  background-image: url("images/3.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}

*:target ~ .item-1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

#item-1:target ~ .item-1 {
    opacity: 1;
}

#item-2:target ~ .item-2, #item-3:target ~ .item-3 {
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="carousel-wrapper">

    <span id="item-1"></span>
    <span id="item-2"></span>
    <span id="item-3"></span>


    <div class="carousel-item item-1">
      <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-3"></a>
      <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item item-2">
      <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-1"></a>
      <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-3"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item item-3">
      <a class="arrow arrow-prev" href="#item-2"></a>
      <a class="arrow arrow-next" href="#item-1"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: data-ride="carousel" seems to trigger the autoplay function: `<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` but Bootstrap 3.4.1's documentation has always been spotty to me.

Comment: i tried that however it doesn't seem to work, i even tried it with different Bootstrap versions after 3.4.1. But the auto play function just doesn't work as its suppose to. Cause it still requires the script to work. and am actually trying to avoid script altogether

Comment: Are you trying to make this work without any javascript or without extra javascript?